Where can I find replacements for old floor tiles?
I recently bought a new house that needed all new pipes and drains. the house is on a slab so they had to bust up the tile floors from the kitchen at the back of the house to the front yard, resulting in a portion of missing tiles that I cannot find a good match for because they are outdated (put in late 80s/early 90s if I had to guess).
Kitchen tiles were easy to find and replace, half bath was small enough to just start over, but I cannot afford to demo and retile the 16x20 dining room at the moment. I would appreciate any suggestions on where to look and/or ways to make not matching tile look ok for a little while.
I’ve added pictures of the tile I’m trying to match and I’ll do my best to describe it: white 12x12 polished ceramic with some very light pink veining (seemingly printed on top) and picture of the section where replacement is needed.

A local store that only deals with flooring/tiles might be the best to find something.  They usually have access to order books.  No pictures yet, but sometimes a different design might work as an accent.

Even in the unlikely event you were to find new old stock in your brand and pattern, manufacturing lots make it likely they won't match well. It's remarkable that you found some already. You're probably going to need an alternative plan.

Depending on how well it was put down you may  be able to get a few pieces under the stove and refrigerator. Of course Murphys Law says the only tiles that will come up easy are the ones you don't want to remove.

I’ve added pictures of the tile ... no, you didn't

Use whatever tiles will fit, and cover with a rug.

Make it a feature - either put a runner (long narrow rug) over it, or add tile that's deliberately a contrast in a pattern (of sections of new tile, or possibly even a different flooring material entirely) that "just happens" to cover the damaged areas (but which probably needs to cover some undamaged areas as well to make it look intentional, rather than looking only like it's a coverup for the pipe works) while leaving some of the old tiling in place.
